# Как вытащить из массива значения SxGeo

Tags: php

Вот массив нужно получить переменную страна и город?

```html
Array
(
    [city] => Array
        (
            [id] => 703448
            [lat] => 50.45466
            [lon] => 30.5238
            [name_ru] => Киев
            [name_en] => Kiev
        )

    [region] => Array
        (
            [id] => 703447
            [name_ru] => Киев
            [name_en] => Kyiv
            [iso] => UA-30
        )

    [country] => Array
        (
            [id] => 222
            [iso] => UA
            [lat] => 49
            [lon] => 32
            [name_ru] => Украина
            [name_en] => Ukraine
        )

)
```

Сам скрипт

```html
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$SxGeo = new SxGeo('SxGeoCity.dat', SXGEO_BATCH | SXGEO_MEMORY); 

$SxGeo->getCityFull($ip);
print_r($SxGeo->getCityFull($ip));
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
include("SxGeo.php");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$SxGeo = new SxGeo('SxGeoCity.dat');
$array = $SxGeo->getCityFull($ip);
echo $array["city"]["name_en"];
echo $array["country"]["name_en"];
```